# How to cleanup the graphite whisper's data?

Tags: graphite

I want to delete the graphite's storage whisper's data but there ain't anything in the graphite docs.

One way I did is deleting the the files at `/opt/graphite...../whispers/stats...` manually.

But this is tedious, so how do I do it?

Comment: in case they appear again after deleting them, check this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501677/deleted-empty-graphite-whisper-files-automatically-re-generating

Answer (score 77):

Currently, deleting files from /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/ is the correct way to clean up whisper data.

As for the tedious side of the process, you could use the find command if there is a certain pattern that your trying to remove.

> find /opt/graphite/storage/whisper -name loadavg.wsp -delete

[Similar Question on answers.launchpad.net/graphite](https://answers.launchpad.net/graphite/+question/157065)

Comment: I'm using graphite + statsd. I tried this way and it works, but after a while the bucket is recreated. Any idea why and how to stop it?

Comment: How do you restart statsd? I am not finding a statsd in the list of processes, but I am having this problem.

Comment: It should be noted that after deleting the unused paths, Graphite itself does not have to be restarted. Statsd is a separate issue, go ahead and restart it, but Graphite will deal with deleted paths just fine. I thought I should clarify this because it was a stumbling block for me at some point.

Comment: What about search_index? Should it be also deleted or truncated?

Comment: Is there no way to see if all the data has expired (e.g. maxRetention has passed since the last update)?  To remove old expired `.wsp` files?

Answer (score 51):

I suppose that this is going into Server Fault territory, but I added
the following cron job to delete old metrics of ours that haven't been
written to for over 30 days (e.g. of cloud instances that have been
disposed):

> ```
> find /mnt/graphite/storage -mtime +30 | grep -E \
> "/mnt/graphite/storage/whisper/collectd/app_name/[^/]*" -o \
> | uniq | xargs rm -rf
> ```

This will delete directories which have valid data.

First:

```
find whisperDir -mtime +30 -type f | xargs rm
```

And then delete empty dirs

```
find . -type d -empty | xargs rmdir
```

This last step should be repeated, because may be new empty directories will be left.

Comment: On almost all modern Unix systems this should be possible to condense using find builtins - e.g. `find /opt/graphite/storage/whisper -type f -mtime +120 -name \*.wsp -delete; find /opt/graphite/storage/whisper -depth -type d -empty -delete`

Comment: FYI in ubuntu the path is /var/lib/graphite/whisper

Comment: Is there a reason we can't use tmpreaper to do this?

Answer (score 9):

As people have pointed out, removing the files is the way to go.  Expanding on previous answers, I made this script that removes any file that has exceeded its max retention age.  Run it as a `cronjob` fairly regularly.

```
#!/bin/bash
d=$1
now=$(date +%s)

MINRET=86400

if [ -z "$d" ]; then
  echo "Must specify a directory to clean" >&2
  exit 1
fi

find $d -name '*.wsp' | while read w; do
  age=$((now - $(stat -c '%Y' "$w")))
  if [ $age -gt $MINRET ]; then
    retention=$(whisper-info.py $w maxRetention)
    if [ $age -gt $retention ]; then
      echo "Removing $w ($age > $retention)"
      rm $w
    fi
  fi
done

find $d -empty -type d -delete
```

A couple of bits to be aware of - the `whisper-info` call is quite heavyweight.   To reduce the number of calls to it I've put the MINRET constant in, so that no file will be considered for deletion until it is 1 day old (24*60*60 seconds) - adjust to fit your needs.  There are probably other things that can be done to shard the job or generally improve its efficiency, but I haven't had need to as yet.

Comment: nit: `Must specify a directory to clean` is an error message.  As such, it should be written to the correct place: `echo "Must ..." >&2`.

Comment: this is great tyvm!